# <DataBase> is being recovered. Waiting until recovery is finished

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, sql-server-2008

I Have Develop an Application using Asp.net sql server and Jquery Ajax It is giving me

is being recovered. Waiting until recovery is finished.

why this message is coming

Answer (score 2):

This is due to Crash Recovery running: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.logging.aspx

You can find more detail on this sort of thing on the dba stack exchange. As featured on this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/database-mydb-is-being-recovered-waiting-until-recovery-is-finished